# File or assembly name ****.dll or one its dependenies not found

Tags: vb.net

I have added a new service reference to a vb.net dll after excluding the previous one. While debugging, When I am sending a request through a form, the new reference is not able to create a object.exception is at this line:

```
Dim ObjPricingService As New PricerWebService.MedicalProductService_V2_0
```

`MedicalProductService_V2_0` is the new service reference. The exception is:

> File or assembly name ****.dll or one of its dependencies not found.
>   Source:mscorlib

the name of the *****.dll changes every time I debug..so its a random one. the code is built in Visual Studio 2003.

Please provide a solution.

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't upgraded to a later version of the .Net Framework and Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds strange, that the Library changes the name every time you debug. The best thing todo, is to try to set an standard name (if you wrote the library). Also you can try to

```
Import PricerWebService
```

and then to use only

```
Dim ObjPricingService As New MedicalProductService_V2_0
```

If this will be not fix your problem, try to upgrade your framework + Visual Studio Version (VS2003 what?).

**BTW: It would be great if you can send us the error text ;)**